# Using beautifulsoup 4 in Python, find a specific string in the table, and extract the text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Good time of the day!

While working on the **scraping** project I have faced some issues.
I have to **scrape** string values from the table, basing my search on the string of tr as in following:

```
span = list()
span.append({
       "Price":soup.find("p", class_="classified__price").find("span",class_="sr-only").text,
       "Kitchen":soup.find("th",text="Kitchen type").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").text
})
```

Considering if I leave `.text` at the end of the value in the "Kitchen" key - prints nothing, however

```
span = list()
span.append({
       "Price":soup.find("p", class_="classified__price").find("span",class_="sr-only").text,
       "Kitchen":soup.find("th",text="Kitchen type").find_next(class_="classified-table__data")
})
```

results in

```
[{'Price': '410000€', 'Kitchen': <td class="classified-table__data">
                                    Installed
                                </td>}]
```

All help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Please share the url

Comment: https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/house/for-sale/ottignies/1340/9308167

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrapping

Comment: WIll keep in mind, thank you for your feedback and corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you want is actually under the next element, to find it you can use the [`.next_element`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element) method:

```
span = list()
span.append({
       "Price":soup.find("p", class_="classified__price").find("span",class_="sr-only").text,
       "Kitchen":soup.find("th",text="Kitchen type").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
})

print(span)
```

Output:

```
[{'Price': '410000€', 'Kitchen': 'Installed'}]
```